# Does javascript allow changing HTML radio button value?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if it is possible to generate using this way.
I have a set of dynamic radio buttons. 

When user click on add row radio button, the Javascript will generate the value for the row radio button.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
   
   var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML; //row[which table u need to duplicate]
   table.rows[rowCount].cells[0].innerHTML = rowCount;
   }


}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="BX_related[]" size="1" value="How to change this value using javascript?">
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing?

Comment: For example, I have dynamic radio button and I added 3 row for my radio button. Then I click on second row.
The value will show in 1st row and rest of it is a Undefined offset error.
So I think if can I insert the value when I crated a new row for user maybe can solve the problem but I don't know the correct ways.

Answer (score 3):

With a reference to your `input` element you can change `value` like so:

```
inputRef.value = 'Whatever you want';
```

Comment: Sorry I not so familiar on Javascript. I just try to insert id="radio" value="1" for my HTML radio button. 
Javascript var radio = document.getElementById(radio); radio.value = rowCount; //rowCount stand for how many row was user clicked.
Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: In the `document.getElementById` what does the `radio` variable contain? Or did you mean to pass it in as a string?

Comment: suppose "1" because I preset the value equal to 1 and I want to change the **radio** value according the user has added the row.